# getting json object to mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose

I've been playing around with casperjs to login to a site and grab some data that I need. Currently I have a json object that outputs data like this but with much more fields.

```
{
    "Activity #": "1-1IMHEEJM",
    "Customer": "DOE, JOHN",
    "Tenure": "0 Year 0 Month",
    "Account #": "12345678",
    "Phone #": "(111) 222-3333",
    "Alt Phone #": "",
    "Agent Name": "Michelle"
}
```

and my mongoose schema looks like this.

```
var workOrderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  activityNumber: {type: String},
  customer: {type: String},
  tenure: {type: String},
  accountNumber: {type: Number},
  phoneNumber: {type: String},
  altPhoneNumber: {type: String},
  agentName: {type: String}
});
```

How can I get my data in mongodb using my schema? I can insert the object right into mongo but my fields won't match my schema i.e "Activity #": not activityNumber:

I hope my question is clear and someone can put me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: You can just change the field names to match those of the schema, or update the schema to match those field names

Comment: I actually want to match the schema. My problem is that I'm getting the field names automatically. since I already have a schema I didn't want to start renaming a bunch a fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just map/rename the fields as you insert the object using Mongoose.

Assuming `obj` is your object to insert and `WorkOrder` is your model:

```
WorkOrder.create({
    activityNumber: obj["Activity #"],
    customer: obj["Customer"],
    tenure: obj["Tenure"],
    accountNumber: obj["Account #"],
    phoneNumber: obj["Phone #"],
    altPhoneNumber: obj["Alt Phone #"],
    agentName: obj["Agent Name"]
}, callback);
```